# how can i save a photo without submitting a form, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

If i already have a photo in my filesystem how can i save it without submitting a form? I would like to do that in a controller when some action occurs.

I am using paperclip to save my photos. so if you have any idea how to make paperclip save it it would also be very helpful.

Paperclip:

I already have a photo saved with paperclip. This photo belongs to a horse(model). What i want to do is when a new horse is created give that horse the same photo. so how can i do that. i tried to point to that picture with paperclip. I just copied the attributes the original photo has. it doesnt work. paperclip looks in the wrong folder.

So I have photo model. it belongs to a horse model.
 With paperclip the 4 attributes are needed: data_content_type,  data_file_name, data_file_size, data_updated_at.

If i then create a new instance of class photo with Photo.new and give it the four paperclip parameters paperclip looks for different location that the file is saved in.

What can i do? How can i save it in controller without submitting a form? (with papeclip(preferable) or without)

thank you for any answers

Comment: I know this post is old, but did you figure this out? I'm trying to do the same thing.

Comment: Honestly I can not remember what I ended up doing. I was thinking for some 10 minutes now and I remembered. I had to assign some default photo to a Horse. So I have saved say 10 photos with photo_1, photo_2 etc. Then on a Horse model I added has_attached_file with :default_url => "horse_images/:horse_random_number_:style.jpg"; which was the combination of random number and style of photo (say racing, leisure etc), the variable for :style and :horse_random_number was saved at horse creation. Not sure if it helps but ..., hope you figure it out.

Comment: Thanks for the effort! I'm trying to have a user click on one record and have it open a new form with the image from that record inserted in the form, so that it is ready to post. Here is my question if you have any more insight: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810317/copy-a-paperclip-image-to-a-new-record-in-rails-4/27811021?noredirect=1#comment44060297_27811021

Answer (score 7):

I am not really clear on how you did your previous attempt, but this is what I do to assign photos to a model object:

```
horse.photo = File.open("path/to/image/NameOfFile.extension")
horse.save!
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using paperclip's default_url option? If you want to use the same photo by default, this might be your best option. In my application, users can upload avatars, but if they haven't yet, it shows the default image.

```
has_attached_file :avatar, 
                  :styles => { :thumb => "48x48#" },
                  :default_url => "/images/avatars/missing_avatar.png",
                  :default_style => :thumb
```

Comment: i do the same for avatar. but here the path to the foto i want to save is allways different. thank you for your response anyhow.

Answer (score -2):

You need to use some Flash (or similar tech) file uploader, as it is not possible to upload a file via AJAX. Some suggestions to look into: [SWFUpload](http://www.swfupload.org/) and [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/). You can probably dig up some Rails specific helper libs for these also on  [GitHub](http://www.github.com)

Comment: It sounds like necker wants to use an existing photo that's already on the server, rather than upload a new one.