# A workaround to pre-populate file_field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

I don't think you can literally pre-populate the `file_field` so I've been struggling with a workaround for the same end goal, which is to take an image already uploaded to the application via User A and then for User B to be able to save that same image as his own too, similar to pinterest.

This is what I've tried:

**index**

`<%= link_to new_inspiration_path(inspiration_image: inspiration.image) %>`

**controller**

```
def new
  @inspiration = current_user.inspirations.build
  @inspiration.image = URI.parse(params[:inspiration_image])
end
```

**server**

```
Started GET "/inspirations/new?inspiration_image=%2Fsystem%2Finspirations%2Fimages%2F000%2F000%2F069%2Foriginal%2Frule_1.jpg%3F1478260961" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-11-04 08:10:41 -0400
Processing by InspirationsController#new as */*
  Parameters: {"inspiration_image"=>"/system/inspirations/images/000/000/069/original/rule_1.jpg?1478260961"} # For example, this is the image url I'm trying to duplicate for User B
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 129]]
  Inspiration Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "inspirations".* FROM "inspirations" WHERE "inspirations"."id" IS NULL LIMIT 1
Completed 400 Bad Request in 6ms
```

**_form**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@inspiration, html: { data: { modal: true } }) do |f| %> 
  <%= image_tag @inspiration.image.url if @inspiration.image.present? %> # I get error: ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: inspiration):
  <%= f.file_field :image %>
<% end %>
```

**model**

```
class Inspiration < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :small => "150x150>" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]
  belongs_to :user

  def image_remote_url=(url_value)
    self.image = URI.parse(url_value).to_s unless url_value.blank?
    super
  end
end
```

Comment: What's going on in your `new` action? First you assign something to `@inspiration.image` and then you replace the whole `@inspiration`? Doesn't make sense.

Comment: Also, you should access URL in params like `params[:inspiration_image]`. And since it is just a url, it does not make sense to assign it as `image` object. You should `i = Image.new(url: params[:inspiration_image]`, `@inspiration.image = i`

Comment: Ah good point in first comment, but trying to implement second comment gives me error: `NameError (uninitialized constant InspirationsController::Image):` @MuradYusufov

Comment: Ok, can you post code for your `Inspiration` model? Are you using Paperclip or something similar?

Comment: Thank you!! Added model @MuradYusufov

Comment: So, what are you getting after you've changed your controller code? First `build`, then `@inspiration.image = params[:inspiration_image]`.

Comment: @MuradYusufov First `build` then `@inspiration.image` gives me the error: `Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError (No handler found for "/system/inspirations/images/000/000/068/original/Wet_Man.png?1478252644"):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `@inspiration.image` assignment to `@inspiration.image = URI.parse(params[:inspiration_image])`

More info can be found here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Attachment-downloaded-from-a-URL

**EDIT:**
Change model according to the info in the link:

`attr_reader :image_remote_url`

`@image_remote_url = url_value`

Remove `super` call

Change assignment to `@inspiration.image_remote_url = params[:inspiration_image]`

Comment: This gives error: `no implicit conversion of URI::Generic into String`

Comment: I discovered this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810317/copy-a-paperclip-image-to-a-new-record-in-rails-4 so you def on the right track. I used your line with the model method he mentioned in the answer, but I get the error `bad URI(is not URI?):`

Comment: Can you update the post with current code for your model / controller?

Comment: Updated question Murad.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: I ran into a handler issue. I thought better of it and I'm trying to recreate the image directly through a `submit` button instead of linking to a _form. I'm close to solving this. I just posted a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40543234/no-route-matches-get-for-pinned-image

Comment: I gave you the checkmark because I'm sure the handler issue had to do with the various attributes paperclip breaks it down into so besides that your code would work I think. So thank you :)