# No route matches [GET] for Pinned Image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, routes, paperclip

When the `current_user` clicks the pin how can that image be saved to the `current_user`?

[image]

**Button:**

```
  <%= simple_form_for(@inspiration) do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :image_file_name, value: inspiration.image_file_name %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :image_content_type, value: inspiration.image_content_type %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :image_file_size, value: inspiration.image_file_size %>
    <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn btn-primary") do %>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin"></span>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

**Outputs**:

```
pry(main)> Inspiration.first
 id: 1,
 user_id: 1,
 image_file_name: "choose-optimism.png",
 image_content_type: "image/png",
 image_file_size: 230082,
pry(main)> Inspiration.last
 id: 2, # Creating the issue of the route error & image not rendering
 user_id: 2,
 image_file_name: "choose-optimism.png",
 image_content_type: "image/png",
 image_file_size: 230082,
```

The `id` is different for the pinned image giving the error: `No route matches [GET] "/system/inspirations/images/000/000/002/medium/choose-optimism.png"`

The working image has `001`:

`/system/inspirations/images/000/000/001/medium/choose-optimism.png?1478840469`

What's the best way to fix this so I can continue to pass different IDs, but use the same image?

**controller**

```
@inspirations = @user.inspirations # Renders Images with Pin Overlayed
@inspiration = current_user.inspirations.build # For the Button

def create
  @inspiration = current_user.inspirations.build(inspiration_params)
  @inspiration.save
  respond_modal_with @inspiration
end
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your controller action?

Comment: @MuradYusufov done!

Comment: I think you need to define a custom interpolation. Wait a minute, I'll try to compose an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Interpolations

In your model:

```
has_attached_file :image, url: '/system/inspirations/images/:style/:filename'
```

However, after you do this, you'll have to recreate your first Inspiration so it will use new URL interpolation.